# What overheads on server-side are there when signing Git commits?

Tags: git

Git provides a way to [sign commits](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work) using GPG keys. What additional overheads are involved on the git server-side (e.g. [GitHub Enterprise](https://github.com/enterprise), [GitLab Self-Managed](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/#self-managed), etc.) compared to the same commit without signing?

- How much more **storage** is needed per commit? Is it only the GPG key ID that is stored additionally? Or is something else also being stored.
- How much more **processing** is needed per commit? Does git need to perform some resource intensive operation to verify the commits? Or only the GPG key ID is checked?
- How much more data is sent over the **network** when pushing the commits? Only the GPG key ID or something more?

To be a little more concrete, between these examples, how much more overhead is incurred on the server-side?

Example 1 - with signing

```sh
git add example.txt
git commit -S -m 'My Commit'
git push
```

Example 2 - without signing

```sh
git add example.txt
git commit -m 'My Commit'
git push
```

`example.txt` (Not sure if this matters though)

```
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way signatures are stored in commits is as a header in a commit, and for a standard RSA OpenPGP key, the additional size is about 890 bytes before compression, which is minimal.  Ed25519 signatures are smaller, about 275 bytes.  The data is compressed in the actual commit object.  This data is also pushed over the network.

The hosting platform must also store the actual key to verify the signature, and the cost there is also negligible.  Keys are usually stored stripped of irrelevant signatures, and the size of a key is usually on the order of a couple kilobytes or less.

The cost to verify signatures is usually pretty minimal as well.  I have seen the CPU cost of actually verifying an Ed25519 signature to be about 120 ms of CPU time, and RSA is more efficient than that for verification.  The difference is again rather negligible, and Ed25519 is a better, more secure choice for keys all things considered.

The check that typically happens, at least on GitHub, is that the signature and all of the user's keys are sent over the connection to the verification service, which does the verification.  Because the signature contains the key fingerprint or key ID in almost all cases, it's trivial to determine which is the right key and check only that key for the signature.

Certainly if you have a large number of signatures there is some performance impact, but overall it is relatively small.  Cryptography these days is very fast, so if you'd like to sign commits for whatever reason, the performance impact is minimal, and you should feel confident in doing so.  I recommend using Ed25519 keys if you're creating new ones and using a reasonably recent version of GnuPG.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly confident that all it does is a cryptologic check of some sort.  Since git itself is doing this kind of thing all the time with commit hashes, I can't imagine it's much more overhead.

In fact, at GitLab we've been working on resource consumption and recently [reduced memory consumption by quite a bit](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2020/05/22/gitlab-13-0-released/#reduced-memory-consumption-of-gitlab-with-puma).  I can't imagine the GPG signing processes make a significant impact on resource utilization - but I could be wrong.